# How to copy data from binary CSV file to local Access Database without saving file on computer?

Tags: sql, csv, ms-access, vba

I'm new to ADODB objects. Not sure if this is even possible but it should be possible, I have a medium-sized csv file which I would like to automatically download from an URL and then upload to a selected local access database.

I can store the CSV data in an ADODB.Stream object, but how would I proceed to upload it to a local access database, make a new table and insert the data and delimit the data?

My code thus far

```
Dim HTTPReq As XMLHTTP60: Set HTTPReq = New XMLHTTP60

Dim ADOBStream As ADODB.Stream: Set ADOBStream = New ADODB.Stream

Temp = http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ALFA.ST&a=4&b=24&c=2010&d=9&e=27&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv`

HTTPReq.Open "Get", temp, False
HTTPReq.send

Do Until HTTPReq.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
    Loop

Dim SplitTicker() As String: SplitTicker = Split(stock, ".") ' Splits the ticker name
Dim xPath As String: xPath = "C:\**Path***" & SplitTicker(0) & Date & ".csv"


' Import directly to Access Database which then delimits and adds primary keys to the data
' No need to save the File on the computer in this case
With ADOBStream
    .Open
    .Type = adTypeBinary
    .Write HTTPReq.responseBody
    .SaveToFile (xPath)   ' make an error handling where specified C:\ generates error
    .Close
    End With

Set HTTPReq = Nothing
Set ADOBStream = Nothing
```

Comment: cant you use the simple import & export function from access?
if you can: import once, save the import steps and then write simple macro to change the source file in importExport xml and run the importExport steps.

Comment: Good idea! I will try it. However, there should be a much more efficient way than that.